# How can I tell if I am using the hard-float or the soft-float version of Debian/Raspbian?

Tags: debian, hard-float

Let's assume that I am dropped into a room with a Raspberry Pi running either Debian or Raspbian.  How do I find out if it has hard float support or if it is just using soft float?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Check for the existence of the directory:

```
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

the soft-float version do not have this directory, they have:

```
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi
```

instead, or you can list the packages installed using:

```
dpkg -l
```

and see the platform in the third column (all/armhf/armel)

Comment: Since someone just misinterpreted this, to make it absolutely clear: If you have a `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`, your system is hard-float.

Answer (score 24):

The accepted answer is correct, but a really simple method is:

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

If your system is using a hard float architecture, you will then see:

```
armhf
```

**ARM** **H**ard **F**loat. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Issue the command:

```
readelf -A $(which dpkg)
```

On a hard-float (hf) system, you will see this as part of the output:

```
Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
```

See http://www.cnx-software.com/2013/04/22/how-to-detect-if-an-arm-elf-binary-is-hard-float-armhf-or-soft-float-armel/

Comment: This also works on custom, non-Debian, non-Raspberry systems. I like that.