# How can I tell if Java is performing properly?

Tags: performance, java, hard-float

There are many different versions of Java and many instructions on how to install the fastest Java version on a Raspberry Pi.

How can I tell if the one I've installed is using hard floats?  Are there other aspects which can significantly affect the speed at which Java runs?  How can I tell the difference between those?

I have checked that [I'm running the hard-float version of Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-using-the-hard-float-or-the-soft-float-version-of-debian).